# Why use subnets when you can create many virtual networks with cloud providers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure

I am trying to understand the key reason why one would need to use subnets in cloud providers such as AWS or Azure when one can create any number of virtual networks? Is there any benefit technically or commercially?

Comment: I wonder what prompted the down votes? I wish StackExchange network disables the ability to let someone down vote without leaving a comment. It makes it harder for one to understand and improve their questions over time!

Comment: Every person who voted *has* told you what's wrong.  Hover over the downvote arrow, and the tooltip reads, "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful".

Comment: Thanks @womble for the info on how to find out the reason for downvotes.

Answer (score 5):

These are different concepts entirely.

In EC2, for example, you can create any number of subnets.  Within the same VPC, you can use the RFC1918 addresses to communicate between different subnets so long as the routing, gateways, and firewall rules are configured appropriately.  You can also make subnets in the same VPC with conflicting addresses, and just like outside EC2, those won't be able to communicate with each other without complex NAT junk.

The classical reason, limiting broadcast domains, is often not relevant in cloud systems because the cloud provider often has odd networking that effectively limits the broadcast domain of VMs to their gateway, at the cost of breaking multicast.  EC2 does this.

Really, in these types of systems, the difference is mostly administrative.

Answer (score 1):

Cost. From the Azure point of view, separate vnets require you to have a gateway between them, and gateways cost money by the hour. Subnets inside a Vnet, on the other hand, offer "free" routing between them.